# Restrict input to suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Here's my script using https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js :

```
function typeahead_initialize() {
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
        var result = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
        if (datum.brand != null){
            result = result.concat(Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.brand.name));
        }
        return result;
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        url: '/find?q=%QUERY%',
        prepare: function(query, settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            settings.dataType = "json"
            settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', encodeURIComponent(query));
            return settings;
        }
    }
});

$(".search").typeahead(null, {
    name: 'engine',
    display: function(data){
        return  data.name + (data.brand ? " - " + data.brand.name : "");
    },
    source: engine
})
.on('typeahead:selected', function($e, datum){
    //You may access the value object here
    console.log("datum" ,datum);
});
```

}
Is there any way to only allow the user to use one of the typeahead suggestions for the value? It's because the form input values must match a record in the database on submit and thus, a user should not be able to type in their own custom value.

**Update:** There are multiple fields that typehead attaches to and they all have a class of `.search`. The user can create as many input fields as they like but not remove them from the page. (Kind of like a shopping cart). To do this, I destroy and re-initialize typeahead within the input field create method. If you do not do this, typeahead won't see the newly added input fields.

```
$('#add_product_field').on('click', function (){
  //Destroy typeahead
  $('.search').typeahead('destroy');

  //..add a new input to DOM code

  //attach typeahead to all inputs
  typeahead_initialize();
});
```

Comment: I think you used the tag java instead of javascript or am I missing something? :)

Comment: Well spotted!!!

Comment: Off the top off my head, I'm thinking a `valid = true` boolean set on suggestion click, and set false on `onkeyup` or `onchange` on the input. Or just precheck on submit if value is one of the ones suggested.

Comment: See update, I would need a way to add that to every input. Plus, it would also need to stop the from typing out the full name of suggestion instead of clicking it. I.E - A user could type 'iphone' instead of clicking 'iphone' from the suggestions.